# Use recursion for looping

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, recursion

How can i write a java program using recursion that computes all the possible combinations involving any 3 numbers from 0 to 3 and gives sum as 5. Repetitions are allowed.

The answer should print all permutations like this

```
              3 + 2 + 0
              3 + 1 + 1
              3 + 0 + 2
              2 + 2 + 1
              2 + 1 + 2
              2 + 0 + 3
              1 + 3 + 1
              1 + 2 + 2
              1 + 1 + 3
```

I have tried writing a function but i think its inefficient. Can anyone tell me how can i optimize this for better execution time and without so many ifs

```
public class Combinations 
{
    static int aux = 0;
    static int temp;
    static void findCombinations(int sum, int max,int min)
    {
        if(max <= 2)
        {
            if(max <= 0)
            {
                if(aux >= 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("max: "+max);
                    System.out.println("min: "+min);
                    System.out.println("Aux:"+aux);
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("max: "+max);
                    System.out.println("min: "+min);
                    System.out.println("Aux:"+aux);
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    aux = aux + 1;
                    min = min - 1;
                    findCombinations(sum, max, min);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("max: "+max);
                System.out.println("min: "+min);
                System.out.println("Aux:"+aux);
                System.out.println("-----------");
                aux = aux + 1;
                max = max - 1;
                findCombinations(sum, max, min);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("max: "+max);
            System.out.println("min: "+min);
            System.out.println("Aux:"+aux);
            System.out.println("-----------");
            max = max - 1;
            min = min + 1;      
            findCombinations(sum, max, min);
        }
    }
    //Driver code
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int n = 5;
        int max_bound = 3;
        int min_for_sum = n - max_bound; 
        findCombinations(n,max_bound,min_for_sum);
    }
}
```

The output for code is given below

max: 3
min: 2
Aux:0
+++++++++
max: 2
min: 3
Aux:0
+++++++++++
max: 1
min: 3
Aux:1
++++++++++
max: 0
min: 3
Aux:2
++++++++++
max: 0
min: 2
Aux:3

Comment: You'd usually start by writing a class and adding a `main` method. What is your _specific_ problem?

Comment: public static void partition(int n, int max, String p) 
    {
        if (n == 0) 
        {
         System.out.println(p);
            return;
        }
  
        for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) 
        {
         partition(n-i, i, p+" "+i );
        }
    }


How can i edit the partition function to contain just 3 numbers. It will divide recursively to include even 1+1+1+1+1 which is not required

@Marvin

Comment: Stack overflow is not a free program writing service. Try and write your program,if you get stuck then you can come here, post your code, state the exact issue you are having and ask for help. Assuming this is an exercise from a programming class you could also ask your teacher for help

Answer (score 0):

To start with a simple solution, here is how you can reduce a 3 nested loops solution to 2 nested loops.

```
private static void sumUp(int max) {

    sumUp(max, 0,0);
}

private static void sumUp(int maxValue, int k, int counter ) {

    for (int i = 0; i<= maxValue ; i++ ) {

        for (int j = 0; j<= maxValue ; j++ ) {

            if((i+j+k) ==5) {
                System.out.println(i+"+"+j+"+"+k+" = " +(i+j+k));
            }

            counter++;
        }
    }

    k++;
    if(k > maxValue) { return;  }

    sumUp( maxValue, k, counter);
}
```

test by invoking `sumUp(3);` 
This solution is posted for simplicity to make the basic concept clear.

It can of course be further improved to use recursion only, with no loops.
**Edit**
Here is a full solution which uses recursion with one loop:

```
static void sumUp (int max) {
        sumUp(new int[] {0,0,0}, max, 0);
    }

    static void sumUp (  int[] start, int max, int index ) {

        for(int i= start[index] ; i<= max; i += 1) {

            start[index] = i;

            if(index < (start.length-1)) {

                int keep = start[index+1];
                sumUp(start, max, index+1 );
                start[index+1] = keep;

            } else {
                if(IntStream.of(start).sum() == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Sum of "+Arrays.toString(start)+" is 5");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

test by invoking `sumUp(3);`

Output:

> Sum of [0, 2, 3] is 5 
>   Sum of [0, 3, 2] is 5 
>   Sum of [1, 1, 3] is 5  
>   Sum of [1, 2, 2] is 5 
>   Sum of [1, 3, 1] is 5 
>   Sum of [2, 0, 3] is 5 
>   Sum of [2, 1, 2] is 5  
>   Sum of [2, 2, 1] is 5 
>   Sum of [2, 3, 0] is 5  
>   Sum of [3,0, 2] is 5  
>   Sum of [3, 1, 1] is 5  
>   Sum of [3, 2, 0] is 5

Comment: I have used recursion in a very inefficient way above. Can you suggest me the changes that i can make to make it effective.

Answer (score -1):

This is your homework, I only made a basic code (I did not try to compile it, this is only for general direction), also I did not add 0 but you get the idea:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    print(0, new int[3])
 }

 static void print(int num, int[] current){
     if(num == 3){
         if((current[0] + current[1] + current[2]) ==5) print (current);
         return;
     }
     int[] with1 = new int[3];
     int[] with2 = new int[3];
     int[] with3 = new int[3];
     with1[num] = 1;
     with2[num] = 2;
     with3[num] = 3;
     //copy the start of the current array to each new array here
     num++
     print(num,with1);
     print(num,with2);
     print(num,with3);

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether it is a recommended way or not but you can get the result.

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<=3; k++){
                if((i+j+k) == 5){
                    System.out.println("i="+i+","+"j="+j+","+"k="+k);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
   System.out.println("count = "+count);       
}
```

}

Comment: Three nested `for`-loops like this are rarely the recommended way to do something, and is likely a terrible solution. But when you answer like this, you should expand: Why does it work? What is your thought process? For others that may come here, it should be generic so that they easily could adapt it to their needs. Also, make sure that there is an extra line beween text and code, so that all the code gets formated as such.

Comment: The second loop `for(int j=0; j<=3; j++)` needs only running to `5-i`, the third to `5-i-j`. Similar considerations can be made for the from. If the sum of i+j is 0, the third loop can't succeed. A trivial problem for 1..3 and sum=5, but not so for bigger numbers. After optimizing, you should try to meet the criterion to make it recursively, as stated in the question.